# Python Serial read challenge

Tags: python

I am trying to read out some serial data that is structured in a way that gives me a headache... This is the line I get:

`b'\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1fI Source:\x1b[2;1fI Limit:\x1b[3;1fV Source:\x1b[4;1fV Min:\x1b[5;1fmA Hours:\x1b[1;12f 0.000\x1b[2;12f 0.010\x1b[3;12f 0.000\x1b[4;12f 2.000\x1b[5;12f  0.00'`

This is how it looks in putty log:
`I Source:I Limit:V Source:V Min:mA Hours: 0.000 0.010 0.000 2.000  0.00`

And what I really need is simply just to get the numerical data i.e., `0.000 0.010 0.000 2.000  0.00` for me to log, plot and do math on...

Any hints to what could be done are appreciated !

Comment: is this the full string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your outputs are exactly the same format every time, I have a quick and dirty way to do this.

```
for i in str1.decode('utf-8').replace('\x1b','').split(' '): #remove the \xlb string and split the string by spaces
    x = i.split('[')[0] #split the string again by '[', then take the first item
    if '.' in x:
        print(float(x)) #convert the item into a float if it contains a decimal point
```

Your output will be.

```
0.0
0.01
0.0
2.0
0.0
```

You can change the `print` line into making a list and appending it to a list so you can do something with it like this,

```
myList = []

for i in str1.decode('utf-8').replace('\x1b','').split(' '):
    x = i.split('[')[0]
    if '.' in x:
        myList.append(float(x))
```

Now `myList` will contain a list of the floats.

I have found a better way, you can use regex to replace the ansi characters in the middle and get what you want like this.

```
ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
result = ansi_escape.sub('', str1)
print(result)
x = result.split(':')[-1]
x = x.strip().split(' ')

myList = []
for i in x:
    if i:
        myList.append(float(i))

print(myList)
```

The output is this,

```
I Source:I Limit:V Source:V Min:mA Hours: 0.000 0.010 0.000 2.000  0.00
```

followed by,

```
[0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that helps me get the captured data into the format needed :)

However (of course there's a however) - I need to read the data continuously from the serial port and do the data cleaning in real-time if i want to be able to display it live...

So, I guess I should be able to split the data using the \x1b[2J ?

Comment: you have [2, [3, [4... so you will have to account for every case if you want to do that.

Comment: @mognic i found another solution using regex. hold on i will update my answer.

Comment: @mognic whats the issue? you not sure how to stream the data?

Comment: Unfortunately with a serial line you don't know where the read is going to break.  You might get those ANSI sequences split in two.

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at the pyserial library as well.

Comment: Thanks - i am looking at the pyserial right now. I know that every time I see \x1b[2J the sequence starts. So, defining that specific combination as a linebreak would then allow me to capture a chunk of data that I could decode using the method presented above and then take in the next chunk of data and repeat...

Comment: if the same characters repeat over and over you can just make a list of them [' \x1b[2J',  ' \x1b[3J', ... ] and check if they exist in this list then split them iteratively.

Comment: @anarchy it would be better to use a regular expression with `re.split()`, then you could get them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

So, just to sum up here. I used the first approach to sort the data. But firstly I read the data with my special EOL.

It's not pretty as it is, but I am still relatively new to Python...
I'll work on cleaning up the code and see if I can do my plotting a bit more elegant.

Thanks for the responses !

```
ser = serial.Serial(port="COM3", baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

response = ser.read()
numLines = 0
myList = []

while not b'\x1b[2J' in response:
    response += ser.read()
    if b'\x1b[2J' in response:
        for i in response.decode('utf-8').replace('\x1b','').split(' '):
            x = i.split('[')[0]
            if '.' in x:
                myList.append(float(x))
        if len(myList) % 10 == 0:
            fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
            axs[0].plot(myList[0:len(myList):5])       
            axs[1].plot(myList[1:len(myList):5])
            axs[2].plot(myList[2:len(myList):5])
            
            axs.flat[0].set(xlabel='Sample [#]', ylabel='Current PV [A]')
            axs.flat[1].set(xlabel='Sample [#]', ylabel='Current SP [A]')
            axs.flat[2].set(xlabel='Sample [#]', ylabel='Votlage [V]')
            axs.flat[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
            axs.flat[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
            axs.flat[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2f'))
            plt.show()
        response = ser.read()
        
    if keyboard.is_pressed('g'):  # if key 'g' is pressed 
        break  # finishing the loop
        
ser.close()
textfile = open("log.txt", "w")
for element in myList:
    textfile.write(str(element) + ";")
textfile.close()

#b'\x1b[2J\x1b[1;1fI Source:\x1b[2;1fI Limit:\x1b[3;1fV Source:\x1b[4;1fV Min:\x1b[5;1fmA Hours:\x1b[1;12f 0.000\x1b[2;12f 0.010\x1b[3;12f 0.000\x1b[4;12f 2.000\x1b[5;12f  0.00'
#I Source:I Limit:V Source:V Min:mA Hours: 0.000 1.500 0.160 2.000  3.41
```